Change in player speed causes a jerky movement
I am working on a 2D multiplayer game in Unity with Photon Fusion. My player has a default player speed (5). I am changing the player speed (to 10) when I want the player to move faster for a specific duration. Afterwards, I want my player to move with default speed.
The change in speed gives a jerky movement especially on the client. The jerkiness happens when the speed is changed from default to 10, the movement with speed 10 is fine for the specific duration and again while changing the speed from 10 back to the default gives a jerkiness. I believe the sudden drastic change in speed is being mispredicted and correcting this predicted value is the reason for the jerky movement.
The below is part of my code:
using UnityEngine;
using Fusion;

public class Player : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [Networked] public float PlayerSpeed { get; set; }

    public override void Spawned()
    {
        RPC_SetPlayerSpeed(5f);
    }

    public override void FixedUpdateNetwork()
    {
        // below is psuedo code
        if (LShiftPressed)
        {
            RPC_SetPlayerSpeed(10f);
        }

        if (TimerIsDone)
        {
            RPC_SetPlayerSpeed(5f);
        }
    }


    [Rpc(RpcSources.All, RpcTargets.All)]
    public void RPC_SetPlayerSpeed(float speed)
    {
        PlayerSpeed = speed;
    }
}

PlayerRigidbody.MovePosition(PlayerRigidbody.position + movement * Runner.DeltaTime); - this is how I am moving my player.
Over the client side, input authority will call the RPC_SetPlayerSpeed to change the speed across the network.
I tried interpolating the NetworkRigidbody2D component to all the available interpolation data sources (Auto, snapshots, predicted, no interpolation). What am I missing?

why do you even set the speed through network? Just use a different speed and let photon only sync the movement .. but yeah potentially it is a prediction issue networked physics always is quite a tricky thing

@derHugo I tried doing it using local variable. But StateAuthority is overriding the NetworkRigidBody2D and NetworkTransform.
Also here's what I found on the documentation:
HasStateAuthority can be used to check whether the client controls an object. NetworkTransform only synchronizes changes from the StateAuthority to everyone else. If another client changes the position of the object that change will only be a local change and overridden with data from the network in the future.

To achieve smooth movement of an object, it is generally not possible to directly change its velocity, but rather to use interpolation (Lerp) method.

Thanks mate. I have tried interpolating the speed variable value and the movement is butter smooth now.

You should not use RPCs for this use-case. This would allow a cheating player to set their speed (or any player's speed, since you use RpcSources.All...) to whatever they want. RPCs also don't play nice with prediction/resimulations, which is probably what's causing the stuttering in your current code.
The correct "Photon Fusion" way to do this would be to add your LShift button to the INetworkInput struct and do the speed changing within FixedUpdateNetwork alone, avoiding an RPC altogether.
using UnityEngine;
using Fusion;

public class Player : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [Networked] public float PlayerSpeed { get; set; }

    public override void Spawned()
    {
        PlayerSpeed = 5;
    }

    public override void FixedUpdateNetwork()
    {
        // below is psuedo code
        if (GetInput(out InputStruct inputs))
        {
            if (inputs.LShiftPressed)
            {
                PlayerSpeed = 10;
            }
        }

        if (TimerIsDone)
        {
            PlayerSpeed = 5;
        }
    }
}

public struct InputStruct : INetworkInput
{
    public bool LShiftPressed;
}

